# Python replace variable with a string in a function

Tags: python, string, function

I'm looking to replace a variable with a parameter in a function

Basically, I want to replace 'country' with 'aus' in this function. headline_aus is a value predefined elsewhere, I just want to be able to replace the word 'country' with 'aus', so I can use the function with other countries (I've got a variable called headline_usa which I want to retrieve using the same code)

```
def print_stories(country):
    Headline1 = headline_country[0]
    print(Headline1)

print_stories('aus')
```

I've been recommended a dictionary, but essentially want to use it like this, tho idk if that's how dictionaies work:

```
def print_stories(country):

    d = {'aus' : country = 'aus',
         'usa' : country = 'usa',
         'france': country ='france'}
    
    for i in range(3):
        Headline[i+1] = headline_country[i]
        Image[i+1] = image_country[i]
        Description[i+1] = Description_country[i]
        pubDate[i+1] = pubDate_country[i]
```

For context, I have a webscraper that uses the .xml feeds of 3 different news sources from 3 different countries (aus, france and usa).
This webscraper function outputs global variables,
for aus:

```
headline_aus
description_aus
image_aus
pubDate_aus
```

For usa and france, the variables are followed by _usa and _france respectively.

I wish to create a function (`print_stories()`), that can access these variables through a parametised function. I want to feed `print_stories()` either aus, usa, or france, and it will give me `headline_aus`, `headline_usa`, or `headline_france`.

Comment: Use a dictionary

Comment: use a dictionnary as ```d = {'aus' : headline_aus[0], 'country' : headline_country[0]}```, then you may call ```d[country]``` in your function ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If `headline_aus` is a `global` variable this will work:**

```py
def print_stories(country):
    headline_country = globals()[f"headline_{country}"]
    Headline1 = headline_country[0]
    # Repeat this for headline_country description_country
    #image_country pubDate_country
    print(Headline1)

print_stories('aus')
```

**In my opinion, It is better to use dic:**

```py
country_headlines={"aus":{"headline":headline_aus,
                          "description":description_aus,
                          "image":image_aus,
                          "pubDate" :pubDate_aus},
"usa":{"headline":headline_usa,
                          "description":description_usa,
                          "image":image_usa,
                          "pubDate" :pubDate_usa},
"france":{"headline":headline_france,
                          "description":description_france,
                          "image":image_france,
                          "pubDate" :pubDate_france}

}
def print_stories(country):
    headline_country = country_headlines[country]
    Headline1 = headline_country[0]
    # Repeat this for headline_country description_country
    #image_country pubDate_country
    print(Headline1)

print_stories('aus')
```

Comment: I'll have to recode all the different variables then, including image, headline, description, ect ect

Comment: @Sean I have modified the answer. Yes, it is a little difficult to edit the code. In my opinion, working with `dict`. But you may choose any of the above methods.